# Why can I access my server from my local network but I cannot access it remotely

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip, port-forwarding

I am currently having a weird issue with ubuntu 12.04 where I can access a my server locally but not externally my router has been set up correctly. I have 2 servers I am running at my house one is a media server running on port 90 that is using windows home server 2011 that I am able to access from the out side of the local network (and I am able to access it on my local network.)

My other server is running ubuntu server 12.04 with the Xubuntu desktop. I am trying to run a server off of port 80 but I cannot access the server from outside of my local network.

I have tried switching around my ports so that 90 would be the ubuntu server and 80 would be my media server. When I switched my server's ports around the issued followed the <s>port</s> server (I was able to access my media server now on port 80 but not able to access my ubuntu server on port 90) I have disabled my firewall (temporally) but the issue has not ceased.
I am really stumped on this one I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any need that you can't work with a different port? Port 80 is obviously used by your router for its web interface.

If you're setting up your own service ports, it's always advised to use ports over 1024. Not the ports below that are assigned to standard services (like port 80, which is a web service).

You can run the service on any port you like, you can easily use [router-ip]:1080 -> [server-ip]:80 and [router-ip]:1090 -> [server-ip]:90

Comment: Yet when I switch port 80 to my other server that was working with port 90 it would work on port 80

Comment: So if I get it right, your Ubuntu has a web server running on port 80, which is locally accessible, but not from the outside when you use port forwarding? In that case, check your web server logs for any connection errors.

And your windows media server runs both on [router-ip]:80 and [router-ip]:90? Ignore this server then to avoid any misunderstandings.

Comment: the logs are clean, sorry I had to work a later shift yesterday